# Have issue with ssh connection when connected to wireless switch

Tags: networking, ssh, wireless-router, modem, switch

I have `D-Link 2890AL` and set it as wireless switch, connected to TD-LTE modem via ethernet. I have no issue except when I want to ssh to a server, I have no such issue when I'm connected to TD-LTE modem directly.

One of my friends tell me that SPI may cause this, so I disabled SPI in my D-Link router but still ssh connection won't work.

I search the internet and couldn't find any similar issue and any solution. What setting is responsible for blocking ssh connections in my D-Link router?

> P.S. I set my D-Link router as wireless switch because I have a network storage that connect to network via ethernet, and my D-Link router has gigabit ethernet port; so I can more read/write speed on my NAS.

Comment: What actual problem are you having? What ssh command are you running? Do you get an error message? What does the error message say?

Comment: @Kenster I get `ssh_exchange_identification: read: Operation timed out` error when I ssh into my server (`ssh user@server_ip`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure the issue has fixed permanently or not, but it seems to be fixed by disabling `Multicast Filter` in my TD-LTE modem firewall settings.